# A field defined by a method that uses that same field... circular definition in Java is hurting my head

Tags: java, methods, infinite-loop, circular-reference

I came across this code on [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTree/article.html#jfacetree_prerequisites) which demonstrates creating a LabelProvider for a JFACE tree.

I'm finding it really confusing however. The `Image` objects, named `FOLDER` and `FILE` are defined by calling a method which returns either `FOLDER` or `FILE`.

Essentially it's like a dictionary saying `insured` means someone with `insurance` and `insurance` is what some who is `insured` has. I am confused.

Why doesn't it cause an infinite loop?

```
package de.vogella.jface.treeviewer.provider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.ui.ISharedImages;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import de.vogella.jface.treeviewer.model.Category;
import de.vogella.jface.treeviewer.model.Todo;

public class TodoLabelProvider extends LabelProvider {

  private static final Image FOLDER = getImage("folder.gif");
  private static final Image FILE = getImage("file.gif");


  @Override
  public String getText(Object element) {
    if (element instanceof Category) {
      Category category = (Category) element;
      return category.getName();
    }
    return ((Todo) element).getSummary();
  }

  @Override
  public Image getImage(Object element) {
    if (element instanceof Category) {
      return FOLDER;
    }
    return FILE;
  }

  // Helper Method to load the images
  private static Image getImage(String file) {
    Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(TodoLabelProvider.class);
    URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icons/" + file), null);
    ImageDescriptor image = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
    return image.createImage();

  } 
}
```

Comment: where do you see the possibility of an infinite loop?

Comment: @Woot4Moo Sorry I was looking at the wrong method. I feel dumb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confused because of the method overloading. The calls here:

```
private static final Image FOLDER = getImage("folder.gif");
private static final Image FILE = getImage("file.gif");
```

don't call this method:

```
public Image getImage(Object element) {
```

They call this one:

```
private static Image getImage(String file) {
```

They couldn't call the first method anyway, as it's an *instance* method and the call is in a static field initializer with no instance to call the method on. But they call the second method anyway because the argument is a string.

It's still pretty odd code - particularly the implementation of `getImage(Object element)`.

Even if it *was* written like this:

```
// Bogus code!
private static Image FOLDER = getImage("folder.gif");
private static Image FILE = getImage("file.gif");

private static Image getImage(String name)
{
    return name.equals("FRED") ? FOLDER : FILE;
}
```

... that still wouldn't cause an infinite loop. You'd just end up with null values. The static field initializer *just* sets the initial value for the variable. It doesn't associate the variable with the method call such that any access to the variable invokes the method.

Comment: Dang sorry for the mixup! But can you explain that last part a bit better - `as it's an instance method and the call is in a static field initializer with no instance to call the method on.`?

Comment: @Imray: Well, which bit don't you understand? Do you understand that `public Image getImage(Object element) { ... }` is declaring an instance method - one that has to be called on an instance of the declaring class? And do you understand that a *static* initializer doesn't have any implicit instance of that class?

Comment: Gotcha... I had to look up what an instance method is but I got it now. Thanks a lot!